# How to use puppeteer and xflow to find and click text using variable

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to setup automation to sign into my school. they add a discussion that i have to click on and type "here", in the name of the discussion they call it:"Attendance `Month/Date`" so i used
`let current_datetime = new Date();`
`let formatted_date = (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + current_datetime.getDate();`
which outputs the date "10/26" which i am trying to use to search for it in the page. I then decided to use `const attendance = await page.$x("//a[contains(., Formatted_date)]"); await attendance[0].click();` which i found from someones answer on here already. When i try to use it the console will give me `(node:15236) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement` but if i use `const attendance = await page.$x("//a[contains(., '10/26')]"); await attendance[0].click();` it works fine, is there a way to fix/workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out i forgot to put +""+ around the variable